# Python *list* "in" operator: equality, hash checking, or identity?

Tags: python, operators, contains

Those in the comments have asked me to provide my actual code, so I've removed the old example.

I'm making [this](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client), and I want two `Page`s with equal titles to compare equal. I've done this to the Page class:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.title == other.title
```

but if I do this, it isn't True:

```
>>> import mw_api_client as mwc
>>> w = mwc.Wiki('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php')
>>> a = [w.page(str(i)) for i in range(20)]
>>> w.page('0') in a
False
```

How can I make this True?

Comment: I tried running your code and got True.

Comment: Same here, ran the code and got `True`

Comment: `in` uses the `__contains__` method, not `__eq__`

Comment: @match the point is, this is a class of my own. However, I have *several of these objects in a normal list*. I know full well that `in` uses `__contains__`, but what does a list's `__contains__` method use to check whether it contains an object? What method do I use to make it so that when I check for an object with the same particular attribute as one of the objects in the list, `in` returns True?

Answer (score 3):

The `__contains __` method for lists is documented in the 'membership tests` section here:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

For your specific use case, you need to override `__contains__` - however you can't just override `__contains__` on the list - e.g.:

```
a = []
a.__contains__ = lambda: True
AttributeError: 'list' object attribute '__contains__' is read-only
```

The solution therefore is to create a custom class that wraps the list, and provides it's own `__contains__` method. Something like the following (note I'm using dicts, hence `obj['title']` rather than `obj.title` in this example - you might also want to test more things in `__contains__` such as type comparison etc). I'm using `UserList` here since it provides a nice `list` class to inherit from, and makes the list contents available in `data`:

```
from collections import UserList

class MyList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.data = lst

    def __contains__(self, obj):
        """Return True if any item in the list has a title, and the title matches that of the passed-in dict"""
        return any(obj['title'] == x['title'] for x in self.data if 'title' in x)

mr = {"title": "mr"}
mrs = {"title": "mrs"}
dr = {"title": "dr"}
random = {"foo": "bar"}


x = [mr, mrs, random]

y = MyList(x)

print(mr in y) # True
print(dr in y) # False
y.append(dr)
print(dr in y) # True
```

Comment: The problem is I have a *normal list of custom objects*, and I want a check for whether another custom object of the same type is in *the **normal** list* to return True if the objects have the same attribute. My problem is *not* I want this class to return true if it contains something.

Comment: Have updated the answer for what I think is the specific problem you are having - let me know if I've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Hmm, that looks very nice. However, I would like users of this module not to have to take these measures to check if a page is in the list - I would like it if others could simply type `mr in y` where `y` is a simple list, instead of having to make a custom list. Is there a way to modify the contained class to do this, instead of modifying the containing class?

Comment: Just make it so that your module never hands back a plain list, and instead always wraps it with this custom list class. It will continue to behave like a list, but have this special `__contains__` behaviour.

Comment: The problem is, the module never hands back a plain list - it actually uses generators; but users might want to convert those generators to a list instead. An example use case would be getting a list of pages that link to "citation needed" but then removing any pages from that list that also link to "inaccurate". Is there a way to make a list treat two pages with the same title as equal? Or do lists use identity for the `in` operator meaning I have to find some other way to make that easier?

Comment: These comments have now got really long, and there's no point me slowly editing an answer each time the question gets more specific. I'd suggest reformulating a new question, with a real, practical example, referencing the generators you are returning, and the comparison you need to do, and close this question.

Comment: Closing in favor of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905688/is-there-a-way-to-make-x-in-x-y-z-return-true
EDIT: how do I close lol