# Is there a way to make "X() in [X(), Y(), Z()]" return True?

Tags: python, operators, contains

I have a custom object in [this project of mine](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client), called Page. A Page's identifying feature is its [title](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/develop/mw_api_client.py#L1296-L1311). A Page is normally created by calling [`Wiki.page`](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/develop/mw_api_client.py#L314-L318), [`Wiki.category`](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/develop/mw_api_client.py#L320-L326), or [`Wiki.template`](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/develop/mw_api_client.py#L328-L334), or by generating them from other methods like [`Wiki.random`](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/develop/mw_api_client.py#L1141-L1168). (I recommend you look a little bit at what that is before going on.)

Sometimes, users of this module might want to generate some Pages and convert that generator into a normal `list`. After they obtain that list of Pages, they might want to check if another page they got is *in* that list. However, this:

```
>>> wp = mw_api_client.Wiki('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php')
>>> wp.page('title') in [wp.page('title'),
                         wp.page('not this'),
                         wp.page('not this either')]
False
```

should be True, not False, because there *is* a page with the `title` "title" in it. Is there a magic method I can use to make that True? I already tried using `__eq__` (for equality) and `__hash__` (for hash checking) ([commit](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/commit/d1956632283c540b6275644a6b3d3782e5a794f4)), but neither seemed to do the trick. Do lists simply use identity? Or is there something else I'm missing? How do I do this properly?

Comment: Your `__eq__` is probably broken. It should work if you have that.

Comment: `__eq__` should indeed do the trick. Have you tried to debug it, for example, printing the url of both page objects and the result of the comparison before returning? Maybe the objects are not being initialized as you expect, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait, now it works!

```
>>> w = mw.Wiki('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php')
>>> a = [w.page('hi'), w.page('ih'), w.page('ij')]
>>> w.page('hi') in a
True
```

Okay, I don't know what went wrong before. This is solved now. I'll keep [Attie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347519/attie)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48905805/6605349) in mind, though.

Answer (score 5):

My original answer went down the wrong rabbit hole... (see the history).

It's *always* worth implementing a simplified version of what is breaking... see below (using these [1](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/d1956632283c540b6275644a6b3d3782e5a794f4/mw_api_client.py#L1296-L1311),[2](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/d1956632283c540b6275644a6b3d3782e5a794f4/mw_api_client.py#L1323-L1325),[3](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/develop/mw_api_client.py#L120-L138),[4](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/develop/mw_api_client.py#L314-L318) as inspiration)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pprint import pprint

class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, wiki, **data):
        self.wiki = wiki
        self.title = None
        self.__dict__.update(data)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.title == other.title

class Wiki(object):
    def __init__(self, api_url):
        self.api_url = api_url

    def page(self, title, **evil):
        if isinstance(title, Page):
            return title;
        return Page(self, title=title, **evil)

w = Wiki('url')
pprint(w)
pprint(w.__dict__)

p1 = w.page('testing')
pprint(p1)
pprint(p1.__dict__)

p2 = w.page('testing')
pprint(p2)
pprint(p2.__dict__)

p3 = w.page('testing something else')
pprint(p3)
pprint(p3.__dict__)

pprint(p1 == p2)
pprint(p1 == p3)
pprint(p1 in [ p2 ])
pprint(p1 in [ p2, p3 ])
```

Output:

```py
<__main__.Wiki object at 0x7f2891957d30>
{'api_url': 'url'}
<__main__.Page object at 0x7f2891957dd8>
{'title': 'testing', 'wiki': <__main__.Wiki object at 0x7f2891957d30>}
<__main__.Page object at 0x7f2891957e48>
{'title': 'testing', 'wiki': <__main__.Wiki object at 0x7f2891957d30>}
<__main__.Page object at 0x7f289190cf60>
{'title': 'testing something else',
 'wiki': <__main__.Wiki object at 0x7f2891957d30>}
True
False
True
True
```

As you can see, this works...

I'm not sure how I feel about your use of `self.__dict__.update(data)`... it caught me off guard first time round... and I'm currently suspicious of it's use [here](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/d1956632283c540b6275644a6b3d3782e5a794f4/mw_api_client.py#L1311) and [here](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/blob/d1956632283c540b6275644a6b3d3782e5a794f4/mw_api_client.py#L1345) (both lines do the same thing...)

```py
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, wiki, getinfo=None, **data):
        # ...
        if getinfo is None:
            getinfo = GETINFO
        if getinfo:
            self.__dict__.update(self.info())

    def info(self):
        # ...
        self.__dict__.update(page_data)
        return page_data
```

Can you make sure that these calls don't override the `title`?

Comment: I think the OP is also asking how he can make those two Page instances compare as equal  when using  the `in [list]`  construct (e.g. by implementing `__eq__` or similar

Comment: Great answer! +1

Comment: Upvote just for pointing out my weird bits. I use __dict__.update because MediaWiki API data is rather dynamic and I'd rather not deal with each individual bit of information. I can make sure that the calls don't override the title though :P EDIT: [done](https://github.com/Kenny2github/mw-api-client/commit/87c34966a19c5d338ac8144dce749888d7a93790)